# DOMDocument loadHTML function fails

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I'm trying to load some html into a DOMDocument, but I can't debug it correctly.

This is the original (unformatted) HTML string:

```
<html><head><title>Pagina 1</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/SxCms.css' type='text/css'></head><body>
<div id='editorWrapper' style='postion: relative; z-index: 1; width:1600 height: 1131px;'>
<img id='editingImage' src='/img/briefingStartP-Stages2013-2014.pdf/briefingstartp-stages2013-2014_1395824936_1.jpg' /></div></body></html>
```

And this is how I load it (plain and simpel):

```
    try {
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        file_put_contents('output.txt', 'doc created');
        if (!$doc->loadHTML($html)) {
            file_put_contents('output.txt', "loadfails: ".libxml_get_errors());
            libxml_clear_errors();
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        file_put_contents('output.txt', "failed: $ex");
    }
```

The last output in output.txt is 'doc created'. I should see an exception right?

Any help is appreciated :)

**EDIT**
Using `libxml_use_internal_errors(true)` didn't help. I still got doc created in my output file.

Comment: what's `$html` content?

Comment: Sorry, that the variable holding the original html from the previous block

Comment: You might want to check [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php) out.

Comment: @passerby I updated my question. Still got doc created in my output file.

Comment: @RobbieVercammen Do you have error reporting on? Do you see any error in your PHP log?

Comment: I'll get back on the log. I'm working on a remote zend server so I can't check it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your error_log on your server?

Also, try, in your catch and see what happens:

```
file_put_contents('output.txt', "failed: ". print_r($ex, true));
```

Comment: printing the $ex didn't work the way you suggested.
I'll get back on the log. I'm working on a remote zend server so I can't check it yet.